# XPath - get node that is changing every few seconds

Tags: html, image, url, xpath

How can I get url *//s02.pikstatic.com/pocetna/102.png* of the image from 'div class=img' node? Also url of the image is changing every few seconds, then class "item" has a new name "item active"

I tried (".//div[@class='item']/a/div") but I get an error.

```html
<div class="carousel-inner">                                                         
  <div class="item">                                          
     <a href="http://blog.pik.ba/2014/11/30/pik-asistent-vas-podsjetnik-za-kvalitetnu-objavu-prodaju-artikala/" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'pocetna_slike', 'vijest-102']);" target="_blank">
        <div class="img" style="background-image: url(http://s02.pikstatic.com/pocetna/102.png);"></div>
                                        </a></div>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I get Null reference exception, I'm using it with C# for Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
(".//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), 'item')]/a/div")
```

Not forget about checking if element which You want find with `xpath` was found.
For example, You can do it by using `count` function.

```
$items = $xml -> xpath(".//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), 'item')]/a/div");

if(count($items)){
//Your operations on found item

    print_r($items[0] -> attributes(0));
}
else{
//Items not found, access to `@attributes` returns error!


}
```

Comment: I still get an exception. I only need background-image link to be specific.

Comment: What is Your error? Xpath was tested on Your HTML code from question.

Comment: I got it working, I only need attribute now for background-image. If I set attribute to "style" I get all content from that attribute (background-image: url) but I only need url

Comment: This is second problem.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. I used substracting. Thank you sir for your amazing help! :)

Comment: Okay. Now i see You have resolved it. But i have done regular expression, so I just paste it. `preg_match('/background\-image\: url\(([^\'\"\)]+)\)/', $style, $bg_url)`. No problem. Have a good day : )